# How to go to last location in pdf file opened in preview app of mac?

Tags: pdf, preview, macos

It is really frustration to read a rfc/book in preview app. Is there any way to go to the previous location, similar to any IDE 
e.g Intellij

- (cmd + shift + backspace) will take me to the last edit location.
- (alt + cmd + left arrow) will take me to the previous location of the cursor.

Answer (score 7):

Go to **Preview** > **Preferences...** > **PDF** and check:

**On opening documents: [√] Start on the last viewed page**

Edit: Meniu **View** > **Customize Toolbar**...> and insert **Page History** to your toolbar.

Comment: HI Ian, But this is not what I want, Imagine you are in in page 23 and you have clicked on the reference, which will take you the probably the last page, How would i go to the 23 Page without knowing the page number.

Comment: Go to the menu **Go To** and you can see next to the entries a Shortcut. I don't know how shortcut is for you. I use a German Version and for me is it CMD + Ö.

Comment: @dante12 In English key board answer is  CMD + [ (back), CMD + ] (forward)